# Does setModelState block such that the next sensor readings account for the modified scene?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am running a simulation involving many different configurations of a large number of objects.  For each "cycle", I read the required object configuration and move the objects in the scene via the `/setModelState` ROS service.  I wait (using simulated time) for what is equivalent to the sensor's publish rate (to make sure I receive the sensor measurements after moving the objects)

I am trying to track down a bug where my sensors in the scene occasionally don't register the new object positions.  This does not happen every time, and the probability of it happening seems to decrease as I increase the wait time between moving the objects and getting the sensor readings.

To help narrow down the possibilities, I'd like to know if `setModelState` block (or stop time) until the next sensor readings.  I.e. once `setModelState` returns, is it guaranteed that the next reading returned by the sensor uses the updated scene?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26198/does-setmodelstate-block-such-that-the-next-sensor-readings-account-for-the-modified-scene?/) by [wongrufus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21315/wongrufus/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2020-12-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This does not seem to be the case.  `setModelState` calls [`Entity::SetWorldPose`](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/gazebo/physics/Entity.cc#L482) which calls [`Entity::SetWorldPoseModel`](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/gazebo/physics/Entity.cc#L297) which calls [`Entity::PublishPose`](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/gazebo/physics/Entity.cc#L228) which calls [`World::PublishModelPose`](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/gazebo/physics/World.cc#L2908) which only queues up the requested change in the model.

The actual change is applied in [`World::Step`](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/gazebo/physics/World.cc#L685) which calls [`World::ProcessMessages`](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/gazebo/physics/World.cc#L2700) where the requested changes is propagated to the rendering scene via [`updateScenePose`](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/gazebo/physics/World.cc#L2779).

In my case, my sensor (Gpu Laser) uses the rendering `Scene` for updates.  Hence it cannot be guaranteed that the scene is updated when `setModelState` returns.  Instead, one needs to wait for the next `World::Step` call.  This may also explain why my waits seem to stop working when my computer is heavily loaded.

---

Originally posted by [wongrufus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21315/wongrufus/) with karma: 78 on 2021-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It does, sort of: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp#L1587
But of course when you call this ros service, there's possibly some delay due to IPC, so you might be better off first calling the pause service, then calling setModelState. Hope that helps

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2020-12-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wongrufus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21315/wongrufus/) on 2020-12-30**:
I thought calling pause before moving and unpausing afterwards fixed the problem, but further testing showed the problem is still there.  After unpausing, I see the objects' positions have been updated when querying `/gazebo/model_states`, but somehow, some sensors (GPU lidars) are still showing previous locations for some of the objects (around 5% of the moved objects) even after waiting for a few sensor publishes..

**Comment by [wongrufus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21315/wongrufus/) on 2020-12-31**:
It seems calling `setModelState` too rapidly models to fail to move on occasion

**Comment by [wongrufus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21315/wongrufus/) on 2020-12-31**:
Alas, it seems pausing and unpausing also needs to be followed by a short wait